# ¿Cómo obtener los argumentos de linea de comandos en node.js?

Tags: nodejs

Es algo simple de hacer con un bash, simplemente buscaría el `$1` y tendría el primer parámetro enviado, pero con node no tengo idea de como funciona y `google` no me ayudó.

Si quiero correr algo como:

> node pepe.js "hola"

¿Cómo recibo ese parámetro en mi programa?

Saludos.

Comment: `process.argv` contiene lo que buscas. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`process.argv` es un arreglo que contiene los argumentos de linea de comando.

El primer elemento (`process.argv[0]`) contiene la ruta al ejecutable de `node`, el segundo elemento contiene el nombre del archivo javascript en ejecución, en este caso `pepe.js`. Los siguientes argumentos tienen los valores pasados por linea de comandos. En este caso `process.argv[2] === "hola"`.

Con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
  console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
});
```

Luego ejecutando:

```
$ node pepe.js uno dos=tres cuatro
```

Obtendrías la salida:

```
0: /ruta/a/bin/node
1: /ruta/a/pepe.js
2: uno
3: dos=tres
4: cuatro
```

[Documentacion Oficial](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

Salu2

Comment: Genial! Una pequeña correción, `process.argv[0]` contiene el `path` a node.

Comment: Gracias @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, corregido! XD

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!, ya la pruebo.